# Where should I add MKPointAnnotation to MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I would like to add some `MKPointAnnotations` to my `MKMapView` and currently I am doing so in the `MKMapViewDelegate`s method `- (void)mapView:(RCTMap *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated`. But as I do so my the map in my application adds the Annotation, but crashes silently (doesn't respond to anything anymore). Where would be the more appropriate place to add these Annotations? My code currently looks like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(RCTMap *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
  # ...

  for (NSDictionary *pin in mapView.pins) {
    [self _addPin:pin ToMapView:mapView];
  }
}

#pragma mark Private

- (void)_addPin:(NSDictionary *)pinObject ToMapView:(RCTMap *)mapView
{
  MKPointAnnotation *pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coords;
  coords.latitude = [[pinObject valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
  coords.longitude = [[pinObject valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
  pin.coordinate = coords;

  pin.title = [pinObject valueForKey:@"title"];
  pin.subtitle = [pinObject valueForKey:@"subtitle"];
  [mapView addAnnotation:pin];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find some tuts and get a grasp of how the annotations work. You'll be adding them in delegate methods. (`viewForAnnotation`)

For `MKPointAnnotations`

http://www.devfright.com/mkpointannotation-tutorial/

For custom annotations (`MKAnnotationView`)
https://bakyelli.wordpress.com/2013/10/13/creating-custom-map-annotations-using-mkannotation-protocol/

Comment: Thank you for the custom annotations tutorial link. I had a tricky time finding current stuff on that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Just to be clear, adding the annotation to the map should be done on view did load and styling them in the `viewForAnnotation`?